# Blue screen when using Surface Pro 3 in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Last night before I went to bed, I turned off my Surface Pro 3 (i7, 8GB, 256GB) by pressing the power button once so the screen went black. This morning when I tried to use it, I got the blue screen. It has happened a few times in the past.
I already had all updates installed. Does anyone have the same issue here? What is the fix for that?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Did you follow the instructions to get more information about the error? Was it plugged in while it was sleeping?

Comment: @CharlieRB I didn't find useful information when searching for those keywords. Microsoft help documents are useless. Last night, it wasn't plugged when put to sleep.

Comment: Details are important here. No one could possibly know what you have researched or attempted so far. We don't want to suggest things you have already done. :-)

Comment: Forgot to ask, did it restart on its own? I couldn't find anything specific about that error. There was a firmware/hardware update on August 1st. No idea if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: @CharlieRB No. It didn't restart on its own. This morning when I pressed the power button, this blue screen showed up. I can't find that specific error either.

Comment: I would suggest disconnecting everything. Force power it down by holding the power button for 30 seconds, then let it sit for 15 to 20 minutes before restarting. Not sure it will help, but since it is a power error, it can't hurt.

Comment: you get this issue: WIN32K_POWER_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT - Win32k did not turn the monitor on in a timely manner. Try to attach an external monitor and try to boot the surface

Comment: @CharlieRB I tried what you said but it didn't work. I found out that the blue screen happens if the computer is not plugged in when going to sleep. The battery is still at 80% so it's not because of low battery.